# Exception when deserializing with XmlSerializer inside an Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, xmlserializer, .net-standard-2.0

Getting into trouble when deserializing a XML inside an Azure Function, where the type is defined in a .NET Standard 2.0 project.

When deserializing the xml I get an InvalidOperationException message `There is an error in XML document` with an inner FileLoadException message `Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, ...`

Changing the TargetFramework from netstandard2.0 to net461 resolves the issue and xml can be deserialized.

*Why can't I use .NET Standard with XmlSerializer?* I speculate that is something to do with the XmlSerializer (as it generates files on the fly) and maybe it's the combination with Azure Function?

Two projects:

- Functions, .NET framework 4.6.1 (according VS template)
- Entities, .NET Standard 2.0

The deserializing code is inside the Entities project, looks like this:

```
var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings);
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
var utalarmering = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as MyClass; //exception thrown here
```

Comment: Replied to your tweet, but we have some fixes rolling out this week that should address your issue. Currently out of office but will validate against the version being deployed as soon as possible.

Comment: It's great you are able to look into this, I appreciate it. Luckily this issue isn't blocking for the moment as it works when changing to full .net framework.